# Resolution changed after saving a image using CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, core-data

I have the following code below. Firstly, in the table detail view, i capture or load a image(the size of the image is about 1/4 of the screen), then after saving the image will be shown at the UITableView. Everything seems going well so far. However, when i press the UITable and try to load the detail page again. The resolution of the image becomes lowered. I guess is the same size as the one at the TableView. May I know what can i do in order to fix this problem?

Thanks.

```
    -(void) ViewDidLoad{
       if ([currentPicture smallPicture])
                [imageField setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[currentPicture smallPicture]]];
    }

- (IBAction)editSaveButtonPressed:(id)sender
            {

            // If we are adding a new picture (because we didnt pass one from the table) then create an entry
                if (!currentPicture)
                    self.currentPicture = (Pictures *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pictures" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        if (imageField.image)
        // Resize and save a smaller version for the table
                    float resize = 74.0;
                    float actualWidth = imageField.image.size.width;
                    float actualHeight = imageField.image.size.height;
                    float divBy, newWidth, newHeight;
                    if (actualWidth > actualHeight) {
                        divBy = (actualWidth / resize);
                        newWidth = resize;
                        newHeight = (actualHeight / divBy);
                    } else {
                        divBy = (actualHeight / resize);
                        newWidth = (actualWidth / divBy);
                        newHeight = resize;
                    }
                    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
                    [imageField.image drawInRect:rect];
                    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

                    // Save the small image version
                    NSData *smallImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, 1.0);
                    [self.currentPicture setSmallPicture:smallImageData];
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the sizes of the image before you save it and after you load it?

Comment: I don't think i have. I got the code from some sample projects. I am not sure how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enter link description here][1]Change this line( `NSData *smallImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, 1.0); )` by following line..

```
NSData *smallImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallImage, 0.0);
```

or

```
NSData *smallImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);
```

Hope,this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

(^.^)"Hi sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Have you tried with one UIImageView and his property contentMode?
like this:

```
UIImageView *imagen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, W, H)];
[imagen setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```